# AWS SNS for sending otp

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, one-time-password

I am building a java application where for login purposes. I will be sending otp to user's mobile number. I will be adding this code in login button.

Can I use any of the AWS services for this like AWS SNS?
Please share links if any.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use AWS SNS to send mobile SMS messages.
I can't put an example here today, I can update the answer tomorrow with examples in Python and C#.

But on link below you can see the documentation and some example in Java also.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html